# c# read value from file and ignore everything except for value

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-2.0, trim

I have a program that I need to have a config file with value to be
displayed in my program. Inside my text file I have Wireless = 1
& Cradle = 2.

In my program I will have a label populate the release number only and not the other
characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string searchFile(String path, String searchText)
{
      string regex=@"(?i)(?<="+searchText+@"\s*=\s*)\d+";
      return Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(path),regex).Value;//version number
}
```

---

This is what I tried and it gives the correct output

```
string s="Wireless = 1 Cradle = 2";
Regex.Match(s,@"(?i)(?<=Wireless\s*=\s*)\d+").Value;//1
```

Comment: @user2190928 show me the actual content of file and the desired output

Comment: @user2190928 check out the edit..you need to pass the path of the file and text to be searched as parameters to the method..also update your question with the code you are trying now..

Comment: @user2190928 you should call it this way: `searchFile(@"\Storage Card\changelog.txt","Wireless")`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string match;

    public static string ReadAllText(string path)
    {
        using (var r = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
        {
            return r.ReadToEnd();
        }


    }

    private string Wireless(String path, String searchText)
    {
        string regex = @"(?i)(?<=" + searchText + @"\s*=\s*)\d+";
        match = Regex.Match(ReadAllText(path), regex).Value;
        label1.Text = match;
        return match;


    }
    private string Cradle(String path, String searchText)
    {
        string regex = @"(?i)(?<=" + searchText + @"\s*=\s*)\d+";
        match = Regex.Match(ReadAllText(path), regex).Value;
        label2.Text = match;
        return match;
    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Wireless(@"\Storage Card\changelog.txt","Wireless");
     Cradle(@"\Storage Card\changelog.txt", "Cradle");

    }
```